# How to call an angular 2+ service from a regular typescript class (non - component)

Tags: angular, typescript, phaser-framework

I am building a Phaser 3 app with angular 6. I want to call a service (GameService) within a typescript class (which is a Phaser Scene). How to make the class use Dependency Injection?

```
export class PlayerConfigScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor(private gameService: GameService) {
        super({
            key: "PlayerConfigScene"
        });
    }

    init() {
        this.gameService.setEnableForms(true);
    } 
}
```

This is the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {

  private enableForms : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean> (false);

  constructor() { }

  public setEnableForms(flag : boolean) {
    this.enableForms.next(flag);
  }

  public getEnableForms() : BehaviorSubject<boolean> {
    return this.enableForms;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the @Injectable annotation to your non-angular class and add it to a ngmodule to make it injectable. But this does not seem to be "correct".

I think you are mixing up concepts here. Game development (Phaser) uses different concepts than angular.

Where are you calling / creating your PlayerConfigScene-Object? Isn't this inside an angular component or injectable? Couldn't you just inject the required service to your component and then construct your config object with your service?

If you're embedding your game inside an angular project you should capsule your game in a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) or at least in a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-game-wrapper-component",
  template: "<div #myGameWrapper></div>"
})
export class MyGameWrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild("myGameWrapper", { read: ElementRef }) myGameWrapperDiv: ElementRef;

  private game: MyAwesomeGame;

  constructor(private myAwesomeGameService: MyAwesomeGameService) {
    // MyAwesomeGameService has to be an injectable angular service
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.game = new MyAwesomeGame(this.myGameWrapperDiv.nativeElement, this.myAwesomeGameService);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tobias. I am passing the classes to the phaser framwork. I am unable to find the actual location where they get instantiated. I think I have to do some research on the framework. I am still new to Phaser

Comment: maybe you should encapsule/split your game from your angular app. do you need angular? there are other IoC Frameworks than angular. e.g. https://phaser.io/news/2017/08/robotlegsjs-phaser-extension

Comment: Hey thanks but, I am trying to integrate a game to an already existing angular project.